# ordinal isomorphism theorem

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, axioms

The only proof of the theorem stating that every well-order is order-isomorphic to a unique ordinal of which I am aware relies on the Axiom of Replacement.  Is this necessary?

Comment: What you refer to is likely the [axiom schema of replacment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), not a single axiom.   What would remain after you removed this?  In particular do you expect to rely on the [axiom schema of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Replacement is necessary for this.  For instance, it is straightforward to verify that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of all of ZFC except for Replacement (the same is true of $V_\alpha$ for any limit ordinal $\alpha>\omega$).  In $V_{\omega+\omega}$, there are well-ordered sets of length $\omega+\omega$ and much longer (since for any set $X\in V_{\omega+\omega}$, every well-ordering of $X$ is also in $V_{\omega+\omega}$), but the ordinal $\omega+\omega$ does not exist.

Comment: Unless $\alpha$ is inaccessible (or wordly, etc.)